# Set grid element next to each other

Tags: python, tkinter

I currently use this grid layout, where I have 2 elements (x + y) on the same row and another label on the second row. The thing is, I wanna display y next to x. Right now there's some weird padding.

x is function-based, which means;
**is there somehow I could set *"y"* to be next to *"x"* depending on *"x"* label width?**

[image]

Current Code:

```
#Frame
frame_article = Frame(frame_feed, bg=darkColor)
frame_article.grid(row=0,column=0, ipadx=100, ipady=10, padx=350, pady=100)
#x
label_x = Label(frame_article, justify=LEFT, font="Roboto 15 bold", text=x, fg=blueColor, background="white")
label_x.grid(row= 1, column=0, sticky=W)
#y
label_y = Label(frame_article, justify=LEFT, font="Roboto 10 bold", text=y, fg="white", background="orange")
label_y.grid(row=1, column=0)
#Preview Text
label_content = Label(frame_article, justify=LEFT, background= darkColor, font="Roboto 15 normal", text="This is a preview text, nothing to be seen here", fg="white", wraplength=350)
label_content.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Comment: rows start from 0 and also there are other columns to use, why have you put them on the same column? use a frame and put x and y on it, then put that frame on row 0 and label content on row 1

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you should define the UI to have two columns. Column 0 holds X, column 1 holds y, and the preview text should span both columns. Column 1 should be given any extra unallocated space.

You should also give the `y` element an `anchor` value of "w" if you want it to be aligned to the left.

```
label_y.configure(anchor="w")

frame_article.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
label_x.grid(row= 1, column=0, sticky="nsw")
label_y.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
label_content.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="W")
```